# Merging Values Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm new to the whole assembly scene, i was wondering how to merge two numbers. An example would be, that 3 in r5 and 8 in r6 and i want to merge that into 38. Whats the best way to look at this problem?

I'm programming on an Atmega64 the instruction set can be found here http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0856.pdf

Help much appreciated!

Thank you

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with that assembler but shift it and add it. In x86 asm that would be

```
shl r5, 4
add r5, r6
```

From what I can see in the spec this might work:

```
lsl r5
lsl r5
lsl r5
lsl r5
add r5, r6
```

Probably there are better ways.

Comment: Looking closer at this, how does it work? My understanding is its taking r5(value 3) and times it by 2, 4 times. This means 3 will become 48 and adding 6 which will make it total 54?

Comment: In saying that i'm writing a combination lock and i could just merge the values and check if it equals 0x36 in hex.

Comment: You shift the bits. So say you have 00000011 which is 3. You shift the bits left 4 times which gives you 00110000 and add 8 to it which will be 00111000 = 0x38

Comment: Yea i understand that, i had a bit of a brain fart i was thinking in base10

Comment: That has happened to all of us. Math with base 12 or base 16 would actually be much more convenient, too bad we use base 10 for historical reasons. :)

Comment: i could also use SWAP i guess. Read in 4bits swap the nibbles, read in next 4bits. check whole register if its 38

Comment: True! No swap instruction in the x86 instruction set (where I come from).